# I need a generic pattern to use in several situations using regexp_substr between some delimiters

Tags: regex, oracle, substr, regexp-substr

I'm trying to define some patterns to retrieve data from Oracle using REGEXP_SUBSTR, but I'm missing way to remove the delimiters used to find the data.

I need one patter to retrieve any kind of data between two delimiters, but without including those delimiters in result.

Let's share some examples:

String:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, end adipiscing elit, -sed- do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore excp 123456 magna aliqua 789003.

#### How we can use a regexp_substr to return data like?

```
1 - consectetur (without space and without comma)
2 - adipiscing (without words 'end', 'elit' and without space character)
3 - sed (without '-' character)
4 - labore (between space, using part of word in a sentence like lab*)
5 - 123456 (between 'excp ' and ' magna', without return space character)
6 - 789003 (without '.' dot character)
```

---

```
with example as
 (select 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, end adipiscing elit, - 
sed- do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore excp 123456 magna 
aliqua 789003.' as string from dual) 
    select string,
        regexp_substr(string,'(amet\, ).*(\, end)')          as val1,  -- 
Expect ==> 'consectetur'
        regexp_substr(string,'(end ).+(elit)')               as val2,  -- 
Expect ==> 'adipiscing'
        regexp_substr(string,'(-).*(-)')                     as val3,  -- 
Expect ==> 'sed'
        regexp_substr(string,'(ut ).*( et)')                 as val4,  -- 
Expect ==> 'dolore'
       regexp_substr(string,'excp +[[:digit:]]+( magna)')   as val5,  -- 
Expect ==> '123456'
        regexp_substr(string,'(\S)+[[:digit:]]+(\.)')        as val6   -- 
Expect ==> '789003'
  from  example;
```

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle regex function which might be more useful/powerful here is `REGEXP_REPLACE`, because it supports capture groups.  This means that we can write a pattern, which may include portions which we don't actually want to see in the final result.

I will focus on one of your questions:

```
5 - 123456 (between 'excp ' and ' magna', without return space character)
```

We can use this regex pattern:

```
.*(^|\s)excp (\d+) magna(\s|$).*
```

Then, we can replace with the second capture group, which is the number `123456`:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '.*(^|\s)excp (\d+) magna(\s|$).*', '\2') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The `(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)` serve as effective word boundaries (usually written using `\b` in other regex flavors).  This ensures that we match only the full words `excp` and `magna`, and not those words as substrings of other words (e.g. `magnate`).

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` does support capture groups when called like this (This may have been updated in 11g?):

```
regexp_substr(string,'amet, (.*), end', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as val1,  -- Expect ==> 'consectetur'
```

The arguments mean start at position 1, look for the first match of the regex string pattern, no modifiers (you could use 'i' for case-insensitive though) and return the first capture group.  It returns 'consectetur' as expected.

An important distinction to make note of is `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` will return NULL if the pattern is not found, while `REGEXP_REPLACE()` will return the original string if the pattern is not found.